# How to secure transfer DBuser passwords throuh intranet server to run sql query on several databases?

Tags: python, oracle

I want to write small http server with web form that allow enter SQL query and list of oracle connection strings  and then shown tables with results per database.

How to secure use this passwords to connect database through http server? Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Securing the password is the least of your concerns. Allowing your database to run arbitrary SQL entered by a user is a bigger concern.

Comment: This service is only for developers that have DB accounts with restricted rights & I concern about leaking their passwords. Best way for me is to made service that will connect to all DBs as one special user.

Comment: In that case there doesn't seem to be much of a need. Why not authenticate users based on the database password itself?

Comment: There is no guarantee that somebody will not modify this service in the future to gather users passwords..